# Customize Increment Arrows on Input of Type Number Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a psd like this. And I would like to turn it into something like this:

[image]

How to customize increment arrows on input of type number using CSS?

```css
input[type="number"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.number-input button:before,
.number-input button:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #212121;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.number-input button.plus:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    max-width: 5rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    border: solid #ddd;
    border-width: 0 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
      <div class="input-group mx-auto mb-0">
        <div class="number-input">
          <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
          <input class="quantity bg-light" min="0" placeholder="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
          <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

But I see this demo

[image: demo]

It show very bad.

The second view is emulated using two separate buttons.

How could I style the arrows as described?

Comment: I want this . Please do not be mistaken. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKzi.png

Comment: Do you want to customize the `+` and `-` icons?

Comment: Yes, I want to customize like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUKzi.png and I am using rtl

Comment: I still can't understand. You wanna customize the icons or just alter their position?

Comment: I want to shrink. This demo is too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input[type="number"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.number-input {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.number-input,
.number-input * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.number-input button {
    outline:none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 2.5rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
}

.number-input button:before,
.number-input button:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 0.5rem;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #212121;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.number-input button.plus:after {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.number-input input[type=number] {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    max-width: 4.5rem;
    padding: .5rem;
    border:0;
    text-align: center;
    outline:none;
}
.number-input{
    border: solid #c2c4c6;
    border-width:2px;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
    <div class="form-group mb-0">
      <div class="input-group mx-auto mb-0">
        <div class="number-input">
          <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" ></button>
          <input class="quantity bg-light" min="0" placeholder="0" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
          <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```